# Simple formatting of cells with OpenOffice in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, cells, openoffice-calc

I want to automate OpenOffice in VB.NET. I have installed "Libre Office". How do I add a reference to com object? I can't find it in com objects list.

I can fill cells with values.

```
... 
firstSheet.getCellRangeByName("B10").value = 12.36    
firstSheet.getCellRangeByName("C10").string = "aaaaaa"
```

But I can't make some simple formatting with cells.

I want to change appearance of cells. Change 'BackColor' or 'Forecolor' or 'Font size', 'Font Name', round digits, etc.
How do I format cell as date? How do I make my own format style?  How do I format cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Bernard Marcelly's [VB.NET OOo guide](http://bernard.marcelly.perso.sfr.fr/index2.html).  An excerpt from the document:

> COM interfaces are not visible from the VB programmer. In fact interfaces are seen as objects with methods and properties, and you handle Apache OpenOffice objects as Object.

To set cell attributes, see section 6.3 of [Andrew Pitonyak's Macro document](http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php).

Comment: Thanks Jim   Second link was very usefull